# Spring Boot integration test not able to pick up the default profile and throwing error when the profile is not specified at the command line

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am trying to run a `Selenium` based test based on `Spring Boot` profiles. I have already set the default profile in my `pom` but the test doesn't see to pick that up.

Not sure if I am missing any configuration.

**Commands (to execute the test):**

- mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=google - WORKS FINE
- mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=saucelabs - WORKS FINE
- mvn test - ERROR (shown below)

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base.url' in value "${base.url}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:839) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1083) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.868 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.HomePageTest
[ERROR] loadHomePage(com.example.demo.HomePageTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.HomePageTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base.url' in v
alue "${base.url}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base.url' in value "${base.url}"

2019-04-05 12:40:55.541  INFO 15512 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@66ea810: startup date [Fri Apr 05 12:40:44 EDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   HomePageTest.loadHomePage » BeanCreation Error creating bean with name 'com.ex...
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-profile-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-profile-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>google</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>google</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>saucelabs</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**src/test/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

**src/test/resources/application-google.properties**

```
base.url=https://www.google.com
```

**src/test/resources/application-saucelabs.properties**

```
base.url=https://www.saucelabs.com
```

**HomePageTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HomePageTest {

    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER_EXE = "chromedriver.exe";
    private static WebDriver browser;
    @Value("${base.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        //load driver
        String filePath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(CHROME_DRIVER_EXE).getFile();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);
        //init driver
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    @Test
    public void loadHomePage() {
        browser.get(baseUrl);
        assertNotNull(browser.getPageSource());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        if (browser != null) {
            browser.close();
            browser.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify any profile, spring activates the default profile. For the default profile, it scans `application.properties` file for config values. So, you need to do the following:

- Create `application.properties` file
- Add `base.url=<url for default profile>`

After that, it should work fine.

Comment: I already have `application.properties` file. So should I add `base.url=https://www.google.com` in it?

Comment: Yep, you can add it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable resource filtering

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```